# Running a shell script as a breakpoint action in Eclipse - CDT

Tags: bash, shell, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

I am running Eclipse, version 3.6.1 on RHEL 6.7

I have created two breakpoint actions, one is an external tool -> shell script and the other is a simple log action.

The log action seems to work flawlessly and when the breakpoint occurs, everything happens as expected.

On the other handle, when the breakpoint occurs, the shell script fails with the following:
[image]

As a side note, the shell script can run by itself as an external tool, but fails when attached to a breakpoint.

Suggestions???

Comment: Sadly, Eclipse 3.6.1 was released more than 5 years ago and is not really supported. Try eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/neon/

Comment: I am working on getting IT to upgrade for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by migrating my workspace from Helios-3.6.1 to Mars-4.5.0.